# problem integrating a dirac comb

Tags: integration, signal-processing

Let:

$$h(t)=\frac{\sin(\pi t(2N+1))}{\sin(\pi t)}$$

$$I=\int_\frac{-1}{2}^\frac{1}{2} h(t) dt$$

when $N\rightarrow\infty$ , obviously (with a change of variable $v=\pi t(2N+1)$ ):

$$I=2\int_0^\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin(\pi t(2N+1))}{\sin(\pi t)} dt=2\int_0^\frac{\pi (2N+1)}{2} \frac{\sin(v)}{\sin(\frac{v}{2N+1})\pi (2N+1)} dv$$

and since $N\rightarrow \infty$ we have $I=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{sin(v)}{v} dv=1$

It seems to me that we can use the same reasoning for different integral bounds, e.g for

$I=\int_\frac{-3}{2}^\frac{3}{2} h(t) dt\hspace{0.4cm}$ or even $\hspace{0.4cm} I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t) dt$

and still obtain $I=1$. But the problem is that $h(t$) is a periodic function (with period 1), since it can easily be shown that,

$$\sum_{k=-N}^N \hspace{0.4cm} e^{2\pi ikt}=h(t)$$

I therefore would expect 
$\int_\frac{-3}{2}^\frac{3}{2} h(t) dt$ to be equal to $3$, and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t) dt$  to be $\infty$ , and certainly not $1$.
just to clarify the context, i'm trying to show that
$\sum_{k=-N}^N \hspace{0.4cm} e^{2\pi ikt}=h(t)$ is equivalent to a dirac comb, and that's what led me to the integral of $h(t)$...

So... What am i missing? Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: How do you prove $N->\infty$ implies $I=\int\frac{sin v}{v} dv$ ? I think this is almost true but some other constants are hidden there.

Comment: thanks for the answer.... hmmm... Well i just assumed that since $N\rightarrow \infty$ then $\frac{v}{2N+1}\rightarrow 0$ so $sin(\frac{v}{2N+1})=\frac{v}{2N+1}$

Comment: That's not true : the integral is roughly from 0 to $N$ so on this range, $v/N$ is not close to 0.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more? $N\rightarrow \infty$ so why wouldn't that be close to 0?

Comment: when v goes from 0 to N, v/N goes from 0 to 1. Even though N will be big.

Comment: Right, but i think there's a workaround: when $v\rightarrow \frac{\pi (2N+1)}{2}$ then $\frac{v}{2N+1}\rightarrow 2\pi$ so the sine in the denominator approaches 1. and the 2N+1 in the denominator can be replaced by $v$.

Comment: so based on that intuition i think that $N\rightarrow \infty$ then $I=\int \frac{sinv}{v}dv$ is correct,although im not sure about how to formalize it...

Comment: The idea behind the intuition is right but it is still false. sin x < x, so I < 1

Comment: Anyway you were asking why the integrals didn't add up, I told you what's wrong and I don't think there is something debatable here

Comment: i'm not debating, i'm just trying to understand (well i'm trying to make my proof work too^^) It will be really kind of you to explain why sin x < x, so I < 1, since you say the intuition is right?

Comment: it is a common inequality. look at the derivatives for instance.

Comment: but if the intuition is correct (which i admitedly doubt...) then                               http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral